# How to add NOT EQUAL condition in ant script

Tags: xml, ant

I have a code like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project name="KillProcess" basedir="." default="KillServices">
    <target name="KillLaunchers" description="Killing Launchers" depends="">
          <!-- Kill launchers -->
            <murex.middleware.access.killLauncher platformName="MX" force="Y" installationCode="" errorFile="KilledLaunchers.log"/>
            </target>
    </project>
```

I  have to add an not equal condition inside the target
        installationCode!="LOGINCODE".  Please suggest me how to do it?

I have tried the following already.

```
<murex.middleware.access.killLauncher platformName="MX" force="Y" installationCode!="LOGINCODE" errorFile="KilledLaunchers.log"/>    

<murex.middleware.access.killLauncher platformName="MX" force="Y" installationCode&lt;&gt;"LOGINCODE" errorFile="KilledLaunchers.log"/>
```

I got the error like below
InstallationCode must be followed by "=".

I tried the below as well:

```
<target name="KillLaunchers" description="Killing Launchers" depends="">
        <condition property="versionDoesNotMatch">
          <not>
            <equals arg1="$installationCode" arg2="LOGINCODE"/>
          </not>
        </condition>
        <fail if="versionDoesNotMatch">
         <murex.middleware.access.killLauncher platformName="MX" force="Y" installationCode="" errorFile="KilledLaunchers.log"/>
    </fail>
</target>
```

Doesnt know how to proceed with the above condition, But this didnt work.

Expecting the launchers to kill all the launchers except "LOGINCODE"
Kindly suggest me how to proceed.